# How to a draw branch of a backpropagation neural network?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-graphdrawing

I need exactly this diagram drawn in LaTeX but frankly, I have absolutely no idea how to do it. I would greatly appreciate if anyone can draw it out in latex for me or could point me to a tool where I can draw it out graphically and the LaTeX is generated. Thank you so much!
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The tool you search for is Inkscape (if you are in a rush), because it may export to pdf with TeX fonts, but really TikZ is not that hard to learn. There are examples for this kind of graphics on the site.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From this question [indexed letters inside circles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123924/indexed-letters-inside-circles) there is a possibility also with `tikz-cd`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd,amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\encircle[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(X.base)] 
    \node (X) [draw, shape=circle, inner sep=0] {\strut #1};}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=huge]
\encircle{A} \arrow[r, "W_{AB}"] \arrow[rd, "W_{AC}",sloped,near start] & \encircle{B} \arrow[r] & \mathrm{Output}_{\text B}\\
 & \encircle{C} \arrow[r] & \mathrm{Output}_{\text C} 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

A simple solution with the `psmatrix` environment (from `pst-node`):

```
    \documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage{pst-node, pst-arrow}
    \usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

    \begin{document}

   \psset{arrows=-v, veearrowlinewidth=0.5pt, veearrowlength=4pt, veearrowangle=35, linewidth=0.6pt, nodesep=2pt, labelsep=1pt, rowsep=1cm}
    \sffamily\everypsbox{\scriptsize}
    \def\pscolhookiii{\hskip -0.6cm}
    \begin{psmatrix} %%% nodes
     \circlenode{A}{A} & \circlenode{B}{B} & [name=outB] Output\textsubscript{B} \\ 
     & \circlenode{C}{C} & [name=outC] Output\textsubscript{C} 
    %%% nodes connections
    \ncline{A}{B}\naput{W\textsubscript{AB}}\ncline{B}{outB}
     \ncline[nrot=:U]{A}{C}\naput[nrot=:U]{W\textsubscript{AC}}\ncline{C}{outC}
    \end{psmatrix}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Here is an option using basic tikz code, and written in a structured way.

RESULT:
[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        %Environment Styles
        cell/.style={
            circle, %node shape is a circle
            draw, %shape is drawn
            line width=1pt, % Shape line width,
            font=\sf, % Font in serif
            on grid, % The coordinate is relative to a grid from center to center of nodes.
        },
        MyArrow/.style={
            draw=gray,
            line width =0.75pt,
            ->, % Type of arrow could be bidirectional <->, -Stealth see  http://tug.ctan.org/info/visualtikz/VisualTikZ.pdf#subsection.4.10
            shorten > =5pt, % Arrow end don't touch node in 5pt
            shorten < =5pt % idem Arrow start.
        }
    ]
    %node[style] (node_name){Text_content};
    \node [cell](Cell-A){A};
    \node [cell, right=3.5cm of Cell-A](Cell-B){B}; % right=2cm of Cell-A is given by positioning library PGF manual section 17-5-3
    \node [cell, below=2.5cm of Cell-B](Cell-C){B}; 
    %Arrows
    \draw[MyArrow] (Cell-A) -- (Cell-B) node [midway, anchor=south]{$\mathsf{W_{AB}}$};
    \draw[MyArrow] (Cell-A) -- (Cell-C) node [midway,sloped, anchor=south]{$\mathsf{W_{AC}}$};
    \draw[MyArrow] (Cell-B) -- ++(2,0) node [anchor=west]{$\mathsf{Output_{B}}$}; % ++(2,0) gives a poinr shifted relative to the previous node.
    \draw[MyArrow] (Cell-C) -- ++(2,0) node [anchor=west]{$\mathsf{Output_{C}}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

PSD: you can see another more complicated example in [How do I draw an LSTM cell in Tikz?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/432344/154390)

Answer (score 5):

one more `tikz` solution:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning, quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
           node distance = 12mm and 12mm,
             circ/.style = {circle, draw, thick,
                            inner sep= 1mm, outer sep=1mm},
       every edge/.style = {draw=gray, semithick, -Straight Barb},
every edge quotes/.style = {font=\small, sloped, anchor=south},
                    font = \sffamily, 
                        ]
% nodes
\node (a) [circ]            {A};
\node (b) [circ,right=21mm of a] {B};
\node (c) [right=of b]      {Output\textsubscript{B}};
%
\node (d) [circ,below=of b] {B};
\node (e) [right=of d]      {Output\textsubscript{C}};
%edges
\draw   (a) edge ["$\mathsf{W_{AB}}$"] (b)
        (a) edge ["$\mathsf{W_{AB}}$"] (d)
        (b) edge (c)
        (d) edge (e);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here is yet another solution using `forest`. Not quite as short as [Sebastiano's nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/443833/121799), but very close.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={grow'=east,calign=first,
    font=\sffamily,
    edge={-latex},
    circle,
    minimum height=1cm,
    l=3cm
  },
  where n children=0{l=1cm}{draw},
  [A
    [B,edge label={node[midway, font=\small\sffamily,above]{W\textsubscript{AB}}}
     [Output\textsubscript{B}]]
    [C,edge label={node[midway, font=\small\sffamily,above,sloped]{W\textsubscript{AC}}}
     [Output\textsubscript{C}]]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're very nice. I would certainly have voted in favour of your answer. +1